# Flash banner over a Flash movie in full screen

Tags: html, flash

Hello I want to know if it is possible to bring a flash banner or movie in front of a fullscreened flash..  and if it is possible please tell me how

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. The only solution I can offer it to add the banner into the fullscreen ad using [`Loader`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html).

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that no, it's not possible. If you full-screen anything, it takes over any other content, regardless of what browser or operating system you are using.